# ASP.NET: concept question regarding variable declaration

Tags: asp.net

consider this code:

```
Partial Public Class MyAspNETClass
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Shared MyVariable As String
....
....
```

2 questions:

1. Is Myvariable a variable used local
   for each instance of the page ? Or
   that variable is "shared" for all
   users accessing my page ?
2. Is MyVariable saved in server
   memory, or is it saved on the
   viewstate of aspx page ?

This is 2 doubt i can't answering by myself, so i'm asking you !
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `MyVariable` is `Shared` it will be allocated in memory only once and shared by every instance of the class.

It is not stored in the ViewState

Comment: So, the best way to  declare a variable visible to all class method, but not shared neither visible outside the class is (for exmaple) : protected myvar as Integer ? (without shared ?)

Comment: Yes, don't use shared unless you know you want it shared between objects.